Should v-if conditionals be wrapped with nextTick?
Version:  vueJS 3.x
Component has div element conditioned by v-if, which is "destructive" in the sense of requiring DOM-edits.
QUESTION:  should we wrap the logic that sets the v-if condition within nextTick?  That way, the associated DOM-edits would be guaranteed to happen only AFTER any current DOM-changes are resolved.
For example, instead of:
<template>
  <div v-if="shouldRender" @click="toggleDiv()"/>
  ...
</template>
<script>
  ...
  methods: {
    toggleDiv(): boolean {
      shouldRender.value = !shouldRender.value;
    }
  }
</script>

should we use this:
<template>
  <div v-if="shouldRender" @click="toggleDiv()"/>
  ...
</template>
<script>
  ...
  methods: {
    toggleDiv(): boolean {
      nextTick(() => {
        shouldRender.value = !shouldRender.value;
      });
    }
  }
</script>

BACKGROUND:  we have a highly dynamic component that is frequently updated by asynchronous event-handlers that trigger reactive logic.  The general question is how best to coordinate DOM-edits so as to avoid hang-ups (literally, frozen screens) in the vueJS refresh-cycle,

Your example code is probably too simplified and doesn't show an actual need for nextTick, but that is syntactically how you would use it...  "the associated DOM-edits would be guaranteed to happen only AFTER any current DOM-changes", that is generally the use case for nextTick, so yes, use it if that is your need.  AFAIK there's no real harm in using nextTick unnecessarily, so if you're having DOM update/timing issues it might be worth trying at least.

@yoduh:  thx.  Another way of putting my question is this:  Does the reactive engine in vueJS essentially obviate the need for nextTick in the case cited here?  That is, if the v-if conditional is toggled, will vueJS rendering engine wait for any current DOM-changes to be resolved before making the DOM-edits required by the v-if toggle?

it's not clear what do you want to achieve but try to remove any manual DOM manipulations since Vue is VDOM based

Typically, you only need nextTick() when an operation depends on an updated DOM. For example, if you want to scroll to the content made visible through toggleDiv(), you need to wait for the DOM update, otherwise there is no element the browser can scroll to. In your example, nextTick does nothing but wait for the next computation cycle, it is the same as Promise.resolve().then(() => shouldRender.value = !shouldRender.value ). The effect is probably the opposite of what you want: Instead of a single update that handles multiple changes, you might get multiple updates for single changes.

@MoritzRingler:  my general thinking is that reactive updates to the DOM should be regulated in a mutually exclusive way.  That is, if a DOM-refresh is now happening, a v-if toggle should not at all impact that DOM; instead, it should wait.  In some sense, I am trying to emulate Java's synchronize keyword:  the DOM-refresh is isolated and any new DOM-edits are linearly queued (perhaps "squashed" for optimization, so as to achieve a single DOM-refresh across multiple DOM-edits in the queue).

I think you mean something like throttling, where a change will not trigger an update directly, but after a fixed wait time? Like you have several counters that update multiple times per second, but you want the component to update at most once every second? If so, have a look at customRef, which is a ref that lets you control when it triggers updates. You could also wrap the component in a custom component, that throttles all prop updates. Is that what you are looking for?
